# get associated model from rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Before saving my `Payment` model I would like to set an attribute for my other model `Post` .

My Payment   `belongs_to :user` and my User has `has_many :posts` and `has_many :payments`

In my payment.rb I have an   `before_create :set_expiration_date` callback.

How can I set the expiration date of my Post Model?

Is it something like this?

```
def set_expiration_date
    self.User.Post.last.expiration =  Date.today + self.duration.days
end
```

Would the before_create create even work since the payment has not been saved in the database yet and hence the association with the `User`?

Would it be simple if I care a 1-to-1 association Payment-Post?

I save my payment record the following way:

```
#Payment.rb
def save_with_payment
  if valid?
      Stripe::Charge.create(
      :amount => 3000,
      :currency => "usd",
      :card => stripe_card_token,
      :description => "Charge for test@example.com")
    end
    save!
  end
```

The payment model does have a user_id attribute but it seems to always nil

```
  SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "payments" ("amount", "created_at", "transaction_number", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["amount", nil], ["created_at", Sun, 23 Feb 2014 14:50:42 UTC +00:00], ["transaction_number", nil], ["updated_at", Sun, 23 Feb 2014 14:50:42 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", nil]]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
post = self.user.posts.last
post.expiration =  Date.today + self.duration.days
post.save!
```

Comment: umm looks like self.user return nil although payment  belongs_to :user

Comment: ah, it's not `before_create`. it should be `after_create`

Comment: with after_create it doesn't seem to work either but I notice in the log that when creating the Payment record  ["user_id", nil]] so perhaps something is wrong with the association and that's why self.user is nil

Comment: how do you create a Payment object? have you added `user_id` in your attributes?

Comment: updated the question with the Payment creation. it does have have a user_id attribute but it's nil for some reason

Comment: you only did `save!` without any attribute!! what about assign user_id and other attributes you need?!